# Find path of resource bundled into a single jar using maven assembly command

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, java-8, java-io

I have bundled all the dependencies in my jar into a single file using mavn assembly command. I have placed the certificate (cwallet.sso) under `main/resources/certificates/` folder. I see an error `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException` when I try to load the path into my properties. How can I determine the path which can be loaded into properties?

```
properties.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Paths.get(classLoader.getResource("cwallet.sso").toURI()).toString());
```

Comment: not sure why you need to store the path to the cert in properties if you can always pull the contents by name. archived files don't exist on the file system. you can't use path to get it. You can getResourceAsStream.

Comment: I want to set them in my dB props along with jdbc url , uid and pwd to establish dB connection. I believe getResourceAsStream returns the contents of the certificate. How can it be used to be set in dB props ?

Comment: [looks like this may not be easy](https://coderanch.com/t/372437/java/javax-net-ssl-keyStore-system)